# How to end a string with $ directly after .* with a RegEx?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to report on a set of URLs that catches all potential URL parameters and I'm having an issue defining the RegEx properly.

We have this RegEx to capture a few variations of our URLs to feed into our reporting but I need to be able to end the string with a $ but when I do, it doesn't show any results.

The RegEx:

`/join/$|/join/\?product.*|/join/\.*`

For another account, we only use one variation which is outlined below (which works):

`^/join/$`

I believe the issue is in that after `\?product.*`, I'm not ending the string (or even starting it).

So far I have tried: `^/join/$|(^[/join/\?product.*]$)|(^[/join/\.*]$)` with no luck.

Comment: Why do you have the brackets and parenthesis in there? Especially the brackets are likely not doing what you think they are.

Comment: Did any of the given answers work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please, make the pattern `lazy` and `$` is a special character for regex so need to escape that. (Regarding escaping part, google analytics may follow something else.) `[]` is used to capture `a character` in a range, be careful with that as well, as you are trying to capture a group I think.

> \?product.*?\$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the dollar sign literally you have to escape it `\$` or else it would mean an anchor to assert the end of the string / line.

This pattern `^/join/$` would therefore only match `/join/`

In your pattern you use an alternation where the last part `/join/\.*` would match `/join/` but also `/join/.....` because when you escape the dot you will match it literally and the `*` quantifier repeats 0+ times.

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
^/join/(?:\?product.*\$)?$
```

This will match `/join/` followed by an optional part `(?:\?product.*\$)?` that will match ?product, followed by any char 0+  times and will end on `$`.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4Qpnx/1)